# powershell search and replace with preserving timestamp

Tags: powershell, replace, timestamp

I am trying to do a global search and replace on files but with the caveat that I want to retain the modified date.
I have cobbled together the following powershell script

```
$configFiles = Get-ChildItem "D:\Test\*.txt" -rec
foreach ($file in $configFiles)
{
    $beforewrite=$file.LastWriteTime
    '"before write' + $file.Name + '" | ' +$file.LastWriteTime
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "XXX", "YYY" } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
        '"after write' + $file.Name + '" | ' +$file.LastWriteTime
        $file.LastWriteTime = $beforewrite
    '"after set' + $file.Name + '" | ' +$file.LastWriteTime


}
```

However this seems to not work in preserving the timestamp. In this example 1.txt had a replacement done however it doesn't retain timestamp. In fact it shows timestamp of change from beginning
I get the following

"before write1.txt" | 05/11/2022 19:25:58

"after write1.txt" | 05/11/2022 19:25:58

"after set1.txt" | 05/11/2022 19:25:58

"before write2.txt" | 05/11/2022 18:00:50

"after write2.txt" | 05/11/2022 18:00:50

"after set2.txt" | 05/11/2022 18:00:50

In the above the 1.txt had a replacement but still shows the timestamp after replacement.

Comment: I don't see an issue with your code and I'm unable to replicate, what makes you believe that _"this seems to not work in preserving the timestamp"_ ?

Comment: because it does change the timestamp and even displays the updated timestamp from the very get go as I show displayed in the output

Comment: It doesn't and it's not clear where do you base your assumption, how do you know that `before write1.txt` lastwritetime is NOT `05/11/2022 19:25:58` before running the script ?

Comment: because it is not. i can check what it is manually

Comment: Add `$file.Refresh()` after the `Set-Content` line